Error after updating CodeIgniter 4: 'system/bootstrap.php' is no longer used
After updating my CodeIgniter application to version 4.5.1, I get an error indicating that the 'system/bootstrap.php' file is no longer in use.
The error reads as follows:

"This "system/bootstrap.php" is no longer used. If you are seeing this
error message, the upgrade is not complete."

I had another problem with an undefined ENVIRONMENT variable, which I seem to have solved.
With my tries.
I followed the upgrade guide to CodeIgniter 4.5.0 as described in the official documentation.
1 - I ran the compose update command to update the dependencies
2 - copied the public/index.php & spark.php files from the vendor/codeigniter4/framework/public directory to my public directory, and checked that all references to system/bootstrap.php had been removed from my public/index.php file.
And I add those lines in my index.php file :
// Load environment settings from .env files into $_SERVER and $_ENV
require_once SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/DotEnv.php';
(new CodeIgniter\Config\DotEnv(ROOTPATH))->load();

// Define ENVIRONMENT
if (! defined('ENVIRONMENT')) {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', env('CI_ENVIRONMENT', 'production'));
}


Despite these steps, the error persists. I have also tried rebuilding my Docker container, but this has not solved the problem.
How to resolve this error and complete the upgrade of my application to CodeIgniter 4.5.1. ?
UPDATE:
I created a new CodeIgniter project. And copy/paste all config in my project. And nothing changed.
I tried to comment on public/index.php and spark files, and I have the same error. I think that all my changes do nothing...

Where is the upgrade guide for CI v4.5.0 to v4.5.1 that you seem to refer to? I couldn't find it at https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html

For anyone arriving here, this is the link to the upgrade guide from 4.4.8 to 4.5.0 https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/upgrade_450.html

as per side note, if you just run composer to install some lib and it also updated codeigniter then in composer require key : "codeigniter4/framework": "^4.0", to "codeigniter4/framework": "4.0" to not update it, this is helpfull in some cases although if you need CI upgrade you also need to make changes in index file

After spending a good amount of time, struggling why I am getting this message and how to resolve it (for reference also check the forum question), I finally have a clear answer of why this is happening and how to easily resolve the issue.
Solution
The solution is pretty straight forward, you just need to update the files spark and public/index.php. You can simply do that from the command line by running:
cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/public/index.php public/index.php
cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/spark spark

at your project root. If you are not big fan of commands or you are not using Composer, you can simply copy the files public/index.php and spark manually to your project from the Codeigniter releases . You need to check though which Codeigniter version you have at your project.
Why this error occurs at the first place?
Most common scenario: Seems that when Codeigniter 4 have a minor version release (for example from 4.5.2 to 4.5.3) usually they are changing the spark and the public/index.php as well. If you are using Composer this is hard to spot, since you just run the command: composer update. So every time you do a composer update make sure that you also copy the files spark and public/index.php from vendor (see solution above)
Less common scenario: (happened to me) From version 4.5.3 and later Codeigniter stopped supporting PHP 7.4. So that means that if you are using different versions locally from your server, this error may occur. My case was that I was using PHP 7.4 locally and committed my changes for spark and public/index.php file and while I was running the exact same code on the server (which is using PHP 8.3). I was getting this error due to different versions that I was getting when I was running composer update. That's why it is important to check what version of Codeigniter you have locally. Chances are that you may have different version than you think you have due to the nature of composer. You can check the version that you use locally with the below command:
composer show codeigniter4/framework


Remove these lines from index.php and spark that you added:
// Load environment settings from .env files into $_SERVER and $_ENV
require_once SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/DotEnv.php';
(new CodeIgniter\Config\DotEnv(ROOTPATH))->load();

// Define ENVIRONMENT
if (! defined('ENVIRONMENT')) {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', env('CI_ENVIRONMENT', 'production'));
}

These are defined in /Boot.php, so you do not need to add them

When the documentation https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/upgrade_450.html#index-php-and-spark says...

you must merge the updated versions

...I think it means add any of your customisations in your current index.php to the new 4.5.0 index.php. An example being a change to where the application folder lives...
// LOAD OUR PATHS CONFIG FILE
// This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your folder structure.
require FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
// ^^^ Change this line if you move your application folder

As of 4.5.2, if you make no customisations, your index.php should be:
<?php

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * CHECK PHP VERSION
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

$minPhpVersion = '8.1'; // If you update this, don't forget to update `spark`.
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, $minPhpVersion, '<')) {
    $message = sprintf(
        'Your PHP version must be %s or higher to run CodeIgniter. Current version: %s',
        $minPhpVersion,
        PHP_VERSION
    );

    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', true, 503);
    echo $message;

    exit(1);
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SET THE CURRENT DIRECTORY
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

// Path to the front controller (this file)
define('FCPATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Ensure the current directory is pointing to the front controller's directory
if (getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR !== FCPATH) {
    chdir(FCPATH);
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * BOOTSTRAP THE APPLICATION
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * This process sets up the path constants, loads and registers
 * our autoloader, along with Composer's, loads our constants
 * and fires up an environment-specific bootstrapping.
 */

// LOAD OUR PATHS CONFIG FILE
// This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your folder structure.
require FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
// ^^^ Change this line if you move your application folder

$paths = new Config\Paths();

// LOAD THE FRAMEWORK BOOTSTRAP FILE
require $paths->systemDirectory . '/Boot.php';

exit(CodeIgniter\Boot::bootWeb($paths));

